# How can i define loop inside loop in increment form?

Tags: php, mysql

I am using two queries from different tables. But I need to output them in a single loop. `$postexpire` is getting me Metavalue. `$query1` is getting me GUID.

My loop is running for metavalue first and then I want to run GUID loop, but once at a time.

Here is my code:

```
<?php 

  $postexpire = "SELECT meta.meta_value, meta.post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta meta INNER JOIN $wpdb->posts post ON meta.post_id = post.ID WHERE post_type = 'auction' AND meta_key = 'closed' AND post_status = 'publish' ORDER BY post.post_title DESC";

  $query1 = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT pst.guid FROM $wpdb->posts pst INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta mt ON pst.ID = mt.post_id WHERE post_type = 'auction' AND meta_key = 'closed' AND post_status = 'publish' ORDER BY pst.post_title DESC"); 
  //print_r($query1);

  $query = $wpdb->get_results($postexpire);
  foreach ($query as $results) {
    $pid = $results->ID;
    $closed = $results->meta_value;
    if($closed == 1){
      ?>
        <p><span class="custom-offline-color">Offline</span></p>
      <?php
    } else {
      ?>
        <p><a class="custom-color" target="_blank" href="<?php foreach ($query1 as $posturlqueryresults) { $url = $posturlqueryresults->guid; echo $url; } ?>">View</a></p>
      <?php
    }
  }
?>
```

Thanks! Please help me!

Comment: Try this `$url .= $posturlqueryresults->guid`

Answer (score 0):

Well you can give a try to this :

```
 foreach ($query as $index=>$results) {
    $pid = $results->ID;
    $closed = $results->meta_value;
    if($closed == 1){
      ?>
        <p><span class="custom-offline-color">Offline</span></p>
      <?php
      } else {
      ?>
        <p><a class="custom-color" target="_blank" href="<?php $url = $query1[$index]->guid; echo $url; } ?>">View</a></p>
      <?php
    }
```

Comment: Instead of this can we make changes in our query.